# What are the observables when a quantum system is comprised of orthogonal spacetimes?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, quantum-mechanics

We are given a system of three quantum domains A, B, and C with the following properties:

- (1)  domains A and B are independent Hilbert spaces, each with their own space and time dimensions. Both are capable of hosting the wave function and all observables of a photon
- (2)  domain C is a [quantum "foam"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_foam) lacking coherent space and time dimensions
- (3)  domains A and B have domain C in common
- (4)  domain C is capable of transmitting null vectors between A and B.

A photon of energy E is known to be in either A or B. A measurement is taken in domain A and the photon is not found. What are the observables of the photon in domain B, relative to domain A?

Intuitively, the observables cannot include energy, as a non-zero amount of time is required in domain B for such a measurement, and the two domains do not share a common time dimension. Position and momentum are also problematic, as the projection of domains A and B on each other is a dimensionless point.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs in the physics network.

Comment: @RalphW in light of Susi's vote to close this question, could you perhaps explain why you decided to ask this on MMSE rather than Physics.SE? Similarly, why was the quantum-chemistry tag used?

Answer (score 2):

## Preamble

After [Susi's vote to close this question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11956/what-are-the-observables-when-a-quantum-system-is-comprised-of-orthogonal-spacet#comment25626_11956):

> "I’m voting to close this question because this belongs in the physics network."

[I inquired with a Physics.SE diamond moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64772559#64772559) to see whether or not  Physics.SE would accept having this question migrated there.  The answer I received was this:

> "The question is nonsense. I would close it as unclear what you're asking or non-mainstream if it appeared here."

When I asked for more details, the first one given was this:

> "None of the 4 properties listed mean anything within mainstream quantum mechanics"

This made me try to re-read your question more thoroughly, and made me try to make more sense of it.

## Does the question make sense?

I will try to go in chronological order through the four properties that you described:

> "(1) domains A and B are independent Hilbert spaces, each with their own space and time dimensions."

What does it means for A and B to "each have their own space and time dimensions"? Does A have 3 space dimensions and 1 time dimension, in addition to B having 3 space dimensions and 1 time dimension? Do we have 8 dimensions in total? Plenty of well-respected researchers have used more than 4 dimensions to model the universe, but most people model the universe with 3+1 dimensions (3 space and 1 time dimension) rather than 6+2 dimensions (6 space and 2 time dimensions), so when you say "each with their own space and time dimensions" I would recommend for you to clarify this, perhaps by writing "6 space dimensions and 2 time dimensions in total" in parentheses at the end; or if what you mean is that A and B describe different independent parts of our 3+1 dimensional universe you could make that more clear. Much later you wrote "the two domains do not share a common time dimension", so perhaps you do want to model the universe with more than one time dimension, but it is not clear what that means and what your goal is.

> "(2) domain C is a quantum "foam" lacking coherent space and time dimensions
> (3) domains A and B have domain C in common
> (4) domain C is capable of transmitting null vectors between A and B."

I find it unusual to discuss "transmitting [null] vectors between A and B". The description of your problem reminds me of open quantum systems theory, in which two systems can be "open" to interaction with a common "bath", which we will call C. If a "vector" is a wavefunction, like the wavefunction for a photon, then the bath C can mediate the transfer of the photon from system A to system B. However, you might want to clarify what you mean by "null vector", and I might be being far too generous by associating your description of a "quantum phone" with the "open quantum systems" notion of a "bath".

Regarding the next (and final) two paragraphs in your question, you have provided five sentences, and the first two sentences make sense to me, but the next three need a lot of clarification in my opinion. If you are going to ask this question anywhere, I would recommend to thoroughly explain the last three sentences (e.g. what is an example of an "observable of a photon ***relative to a*** domain/Hilbert-space"; why does the fact that a measurement takes a non-zero amount of time to make, mean that "the observables cannot include energy"; what do you mean by the "projection of domain A on B" and why is it a dimensionless "point" and why does that make "position and momentum problematic"?).

Comment: This is really going beyond the extra mile just to answer this question. Take my upvote. One could have instead replied that the OP's condition (3) contradicts (1) and (2); in (1), it is assumed that A and B have sensible space and time while (2) asserts C does not, yet somehow (3) requires C to be a subdomain of both A and B. It is just not clear enough what "quantum domain", "independent Hilbert space", etc means to the OP, because it is not what it means to physics. It should be closed for lacking clarity.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent At first, I also interpreted (3) as saying that C is a subdomain of A and B, but it actually doesn't say that it's a subdomain, and that's why the idea from open quantum systems theory of a "bath" felt like the best interpretation for me, although it's not really the same as a "quantum foam". As for closing the question, by answering it I have removed it from the "unanswered queue", so it will be less visible to anyone looking there. If someone wants to write a better answer they're welcome to do that, [**see here**](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/228/5)

Comment: Thank you very much for considering my question! The framing of the question is clearly lacking. I was referring to six space and two time dimensions. I was hoping the answer to this question might make reference to Dark Matter, as I see this as a compelling model for DM. I shall enjoy looking in to open quantum systems.The Physics SE does not accept my questions. Please delete this question if it is not appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify the assumptions concerning Domain C: The underlying quantum structure of the vacuum is often taken as a quantum foam. One basic property of this structure is transparency to null vectors, such as EM fields and gravitational waves (it must have this property otherwise the vacuum would be opaque and presumably stiff). It is this property assumed for Domain C.